# pyspark, can you somehow pass pyspark's SparkContext to a java object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

So as per a well known spark bug/design limitation https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243 you can't have multiple SparkContexts. Now, I am doing this really ugly mixture of python and Scala and I have a Scala method that expects a SparkContext as an argument. Can I somehow instantiate this Scala object in `py4j` and then pass it pyspark's SparkContext (exported as `sc` in the pyspark shell). My understanding is that `sc` is a thin wrapper around a Scala object, but I can't figure out how to convert it to a java/scala class and pass it as an argument to my Scala method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `SparkContext.getOrCreate()` in Scala to get the active `SparkContext` created by PySpark.

Comment: Thanks that seems like it would work. I will do it later today and post back.